# Где Visual Studio хранит мусор после установки обновления?

Tags: visual-studio

После установки каждого обновления, отжирается значительный кусок места на HDD. Я подозреваю, что Visual Studio куда-то сливает скаченные обновления перед установкой, но потом за собой не подчищает.

Где найти эти файлы?

Удаление мусора через стандартную утилиту Windows не находит их.

Comment: может в временных файлах висит где-то?

Comment: Скачайте какой-нибудь анализатор занятого места на диске (WinDirStat) и проанализируйте, например

Comment: Используйте приложение анализатор занятого места на диске (типа SpaceSniffer, WinDirStat, Scanner by steffen gerlach). Оно покажет вам карту занятого пространства на диске.

Comment: Папка Temp, либо прям на диске C лежат папки "VisualStudio" и "MSSQLServer201#"

Comment: Картинку эти утилитки выдают красивую, жаль что толку с нее ноль. Размер подкаталога можно и без картинки посмотреть, в Total Commander, например. Только это никак не поможет определить куда инсталлер VS накидал мусора.

Comment: @freim почему это? Сортируем по убыванию размера, и каталоги с мусором VS будут примерно в самом начале списка

Comment: @andreymal, мой каталог в Users - это 21Гб, 227295 файлов в 47488 каталогах. Выделить из этой горы хлама данные отдельной программы, даже примерно зная где смотреть, это задачка еще та. Мне как-то приходилось вручную удалять неудачное обновление Android Studio, мало не показалось. По картинке на экране уж точно ничего там не найдешь, эти утилитки скорее из категории красивых безделушек.

Comment: @freim у вас все 47488 каталогов лежат прямо в каталоге Users без дополнительных подкаталогов? Нет, не верю. Если нет — скорее всего у вас в каталоге Users не более чем несколько десятков подкаталогов, которые отлично сортируются по размеру и всё отлично смотрится, особенно если знать где смотреть

Comment: @freim и если у вас Android Studio находится более чем в одном каталоге, то вы явно что-то делаете не так. Когда я ставил себе Android Studio, он располагался ровно в одном каталоге, который так и называется Android Studio

Comment: @andreymal, не представляю, как сортировка по размеру поможет выделить именно файлы VS. Там что, кроме VS никто большие файлы не держит? Хотя не буду спорить, в отличие от SpaceSniffer, WinDirStat выглядит полезнее. Не только картинку рисует. Не панацея, но задачу облегчит. Насчет Android Studio в одном каталоге - смешно, да. Загляните в AppData хотя бы, а он ведь не только там мусорит.

Comment: @freim «как сортировка по размеру поможет выделить именно файлы VS» — очевидно, в названии больших каталогов будет тем или иным образом упоминаться VS. // «кроме VS никто большие файлы не держит?» — держит конечно, только в названиях других каталогов не будет упоминаться VS. // «Загляните в AppData хотя бы» — в линуксе с AppData проблематично)

Comment: @andreymal, "*очевидно, в названии больших каталогов будет тем или иным образом упоминаться VS*" совсем неочевидно, и очень часто неверно. "*в линуксе с AppData проблематично*" - вполне возможно, что в линуксе все проще, но разговор здесь вроде про Windows. Пора заканчивать, я думаю.

Comment: @freim «и очень часто неверно» — вот если с помощью WinDirStat найти не удастся, тогда и поговорим :)